# Android Camera App : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception

I am developing an app that enables the user to press a button and record a video and whenever he presses stop the video is saved and then a thumbnail of the video is displayed in an ImageView. Here is the source code:

```
public class Home extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private Uri fileUri;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Button openCam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


        openCam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //send request to capture video
                Intent myVideo = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                //video save file
                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

                myVideo.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                //set high quality
                myVideo.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                //set camera roll to 25sec length
                myVideo.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,25);
                //execute intent, camera opens for the user to capture vid
                startActivityForResult(myVideo, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            String path = fileUri.getPath().toString(); <-- line 76

            Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(thumb);
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the video capture
            } else {
             //Video capture failed, advise user
            }
        }


    }
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    //create file to store video
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "MyCameraApp");
        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

The thing is that when I launch my app on my emulator(Genymotion) everything works the way it is supposed to, BUT when I run it on a real Android device the app force closes the minute the user stops recording.

This is the output I get from Logat:

```
03-17 15:23:06.379  20159-20159/com.example.manolis.mrw E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.manolis.mrw, PID: 20159
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.manolis.mrw/com.example.manolis.mrw.Home}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=200, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/MyCameraApp/VID_20150317_152258.mp4 }} to activity {com.example.manolis.mrw/com.example.manolis.mrw.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5196)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=200, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/MyCameraApp/VID_20150317_152258.mp4 }} to activity {com.example.manolis.mrw/com.example.manolis.mrw.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3499)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5196)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.manolis.mrw.Home.onActivityResult(Home.java:76)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5432)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5196)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening ? Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your `Activity` is being destroyed for some reason, therefore your `fileUri` will be `null` at this point.
I would have done something like this in your `onActivityResult`:

```
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
String path = fileUri.getPath().toString();
```

Also, you are returning `null` in some cases on your method, so you need to make a null check anyway.

Comment: so you suggest to delete fileUri and move it to onActivityResult?

Comment: I'm suggesting you add the line I wrote before doing getPath(). You are only trying to read the path onActivityResult, and this path is static, so you can refer do it again safely without having the nullpointer in case your activity gets destroyed.

Comment: Keep the same code you have, just add what I wrote.

Comment: Your suggestion worked! but now the video's thumbnail is not displayed in ImageView.

Comment: Yeah alright, it's because "String timeStamp" will give you a different name, since it not the same timestamp when you clicked on it and when you receive the video in onActivityResult. I would have stored the path after onClick, and use that path later on. You can saved it in SharedPreferences, something like "currentVideoPath" i.e